# Social trust/faith in political system datasets for Africa pre-2000?

Tags: africa, politics, survey

I am looking for data that covers social trust/trust in elected officials/political system/etc. data for Africa pre-2000. Afrobarometer/WVS have good coverage until around 1999 though do not have the variables I am looking for, and I was wondering if there were any datasets that cover earlier years?

Answer (score 1):

For 1995-1999, there would be the *[Corruption Perception Index](https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/1995)* from *Transparency International* which includes some African countries.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Will keep this thread open to see if there are any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The HUMAN surveys (accessible through the [Harvard Dataverse](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataverse/humansurveys)) contain information on social trust, satisfaction with and support for democracy, and perceived electoral integrity, for *some* African states post 2000. Though coverage is more comprehensive after 2000.